# How can I set many formats for barcode scanner or exclude couple?

Tags: android, qr-code

This code set scanner only for QR codes:

```
mBarcodeDetector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(mContext)
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build();
```

But I want more formats.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can select all formats that you need:

```
BarcodeDetector detector = new BarcodeDetector.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setBarcodeFormats(Barcode.DATA_MATRIX | Barcode.QR_CODE)
                    .build();
```

From [the doc](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/vision/barcode/BarcodeDetector.Builder.html#setBarcodeFormats(int)):

> Bit mask (containing values like QR_CODE and so on) that selects which formats this barcode detector should recognize.
>
> The full list of supported format constants is:
>
> - ALL_FORMATS
> - AZTEC
> - CODE_128
> - CODE_39
> - CODE_93
> - CODABAR
> - DATA_MATRIX
> - EAN_13
> - EAN_8
> - ITF
> - PDF417
> - QR_CODE
> - UPC_A
> - UPC_E
>
> By default, the detector will recognize all supported formats. This corresponds to the special **ALL_FORMATS** constant.

[Here](https://search-codelabs.appspot.com/codelabs/bar-codes#6) you have a barcode detection sample using the Mobile Vision API.